# Django context processor 'AnonymousUser' object is not iterable

Tags: django

I'm new to Django and have the below context processor which passes some data which is displayed in the header. everything works ok until the user logs out which should direct them back to the login screen however I get the below error.

[image: error 1]

here is the code

```py
from . models import Job
from datetime import date

def add_variable_to_context(request):

    today = date.today()
    engineers_jobs = Job.objects.filter(date_due__lte = today).filter(assigned_to=request.user)
    engineer_overdue = 0
    for job in engineers_jobs:
        engineer_overdue += 1

    return {
        'engineers_jobs': engineers_jobs,
        'engineer_overdue':engineer_overdue,
    }
```

I then tried the below

```py
from . models import Job
from datetime import date

def add_variable_to_context(request):

    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        today = date.today()
        engineers_jobs = Job.objects.filter(date_due__lte = today).filter(assigned_to=request.user)
        engineer_overdue = 0
        for job in engineers_jobs:
            engineer_overdue += 1

        return {
            'engineers_jobs': engineers_jobs,
            'engineer_overdue':engineer_overdue,
        }
```

but that displayed the following error
[image: error2]
can someone help me where I am going wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Context processors must return a dictionary.

When the user is not logged in you are currently returning `None`, you should return an empty dictionary instead

```
from . models import Job
from datetime import date

def add_variable_to_context(request):

    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        today = date.today()
        engineers_jobs = Job.objects.filter(date_due__lte = today).filter(assigned_to=request.user)
        engineer_overdue = 0
        for job in engineers_jobs:
            engineer_overdue += 1

        return {
            'engineers_jobs': engineers_jobs,
            'engineer_overdue':engineer_overdue,
        }
    return {}
```